# Why are all configs lost when starting Jenkins as another user on Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, redhat

I have Jenkins running on Tomcat on a Red Hat machine. I have started the server with my own Linux username. If I start the same server as root user, then the Jenkins dashboard and everything will be empty. Why does this happen? I would like to start the Tomcat server as any user and find all the same Jenkins configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an issue with where Jenkins expects to find its configuration files.  If you have the environment variable JENKINS_HOME defined, it will look in $JENKINS_HOME, otherwise it will use the subdirectory .jenkins in the home directory of the user running the Tomcat server.

In your case, I'm guessing that the Jenkins configuration files are in .jenkins under the home directory of the user that you first started Jenkins with.

See the [Jenkins administration documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) for more details.

Comment: Can also be related to file-system permissions, which is basically the same issue - different users will have different configurations.